# EmberJS ArrayControlller Resets Selection After Sort

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Whenever one changes the `sortingProperties` in my `ArrayController`, the selected checkboxes are always reset for all records. Is there a way to persist the state of the specific record? I've tried to swap `controller` for `content` and `arrangedContent` in my keywords template.

#### KeywordView

```handlebars
{{view Ember.Checkbox
       class="keyword-checkbox"
       idBinding="checkboxId"
       name="id[]"
       disabledBinding="isCheckboxDisabled"
       checkedBinding="isKeywordSelected"
       valueBinding="id" }}
```

#### KeywordController

```js
App.KeywordController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(Ember.Evented, {
    ...
    isKeywordSelected: false
    ...
});
```

#### KeywordsControlller

```js
App.KeywordsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(Ember.Evented, {
    sortAscending: true,
    sortProperties: ['name'],

    init: function() {
        this.set('content', this.store.find('keyword', { domain_id: 1 });
    }
});
```

#### KeywordsTemplate

```js
{{#each keyword in controller}}
    {{render "keyword" keyword}}
{{/each}}
```

#### Update: jsFiddle Example

http://jsfiddle.net/rxgx/pJUuc/

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: @Edu added a jsFiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some changes in your code this goes well now.

I changed the each block to use arrangedContent and the partial helper, that renders a template with the actual context...

```
{{#each arrangedContent}}
  {{partial keyword}}
{{/each}}
```

Also in the keywords controller I added an itemController property to assing the controllers for the items and in the init method I added a call to this._super() to call the ember initialitation code for the controller.

```
App.KeywordsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController:'keyword',
    selectedKeywords: function() {
        return this.get('content').filterBy('isSelected', true).get('length');
    }.property('content.@each.isSelected'),

    sortAscending: true,
    sortProperties: ['name'],

    actions: {
        sort: function(property) {console.log(property);
            this.set('sortProperties', [property]);
        }
    },

    init: function() {
        this.set('content', keywords);
        this._super();    
    }
});
```

the Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pJUuc/6/

Comment: I'll give this a try and see how it goes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have a keywords controller which is an ArrayController. When you call render an ObjectController is created for each keyword. Place the state in a KeywordController that way the state is scoped to the individual keyword and not the collection.